# Star pattern to make a hollow butterfly in python

Tags: python, loops

I wrote this program I've given below to make a hollow butterfly, but I am not getting the desired results.

```
type n=int(input('enter number of rows the double of which you want in your butterfly:'))
a=input('enter the symbol you want to make your butter-fly with:')
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        if j==0 or i==n-1 or j==i:
            print(a,end=" ")
        else:
            print(' ',end=" ")
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("",end="")
    for j in range(i,n-1):
        print(" ", end='')
    for j in range(i,n):
        print("",end="")
    for j in range(i,n):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i + 1):
        if i==n-1 or j==n-1 or i+j==n-1:
            print(a, end=" ")
        else:
            print(' ', end=" ")
    print()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        if i==0 or j==i or j==n-1:
            print(a,end=" ")
        else:
            print(' ', end=" ")
    for j in range(i, n):
        print("", end="")
    for j in range(i + 1 - 1):
        print(" ", end="")
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print("", end="")
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i,n):
        if i==0 or j==n-1 or i==j:
            print(a, end=" ")
        else:
            print(' ', end=" ")
    print()here
```

When I run it, I get something like this:

```
*
* *
*   *          *
*     *      *
* * * * *  * * * * *
* * * * *  * * * * *
*     *    *     *
*   *      *   *
* *        * *
*          *
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the conditions in the *if* blocks?

Comment: What's the point of `print("",end="")`? It prints an empty string with an empty end, so it doesn't print anything. I suspect that's part of the problem.

Comment: Please add what the result is supposed to look like.

Comment: `print()here` is a syntax error, probably a copying error. Please edit to show what you're really executing.

Comment: so should i remove the end=' ' part?

Comment: `type n` is also invalid.

Comment: That will make it print a bunch of blank lines. Is that what you want?

Comment: well yes i want the balnk lines so i can create the shape of the butterfly

Comment: Like I said above, please show what the result should be.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH23E.png is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: That's not your code though is it?

Comment: it is not homework. that was the first picture i could find when they asked me to show what the result should look like, and so i linked it. i was just trying these patterns out on my own.

Comment: @imhere There are no blank lines in that picture.

Comment: Please paste the desired result into the question as text. Use a code block like I did for the actual output, so it will be formatted properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the logic before coding and only start coding when you are sure your logic works. This approach saves you a lot of time. Instead of thinking where `*` won't be printed, think where it must be. Following is a pseudocode for a program which generates a hollow butterfly:

```
for i → number_of_rows:
  for j → number_of_rows:
     if j = 0 OR j = i OR j = n - i - 1 OR j = n - 1:
        print '*'
     else 
        print ' '
  print 'new_line'
```

Output:

```
*                 * 
* *             * * 
*   *         *   * 
*     *     *     * 
*       * *       * 
*       * *       * 
*     *     *     * 
*   *         *   * 
* *             * * 
*                 *
```

**Explanation**:

- print '*' when `j=0` because first column "always" have stars
- print '*' when `j=i` and `j=n-i-1` because diagonals always have stars
- print '*' when `j=n-1` because last column always have stars
- Everywhere else print `' '`

You can now try this logic in python.

**Update**:

Someone pointed out that my output is different than the desired output. Below is a code which produces desired output:

```py
n = 10  
a = '*' 
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j == 0 or j == i or j == n - i - 1 or j == n - 1:
            print(a, end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
    print()
```

```
Output:
*        *
**      **
* *    * *
*  *  *  *
*   **   *
*   **   *
*  *  *  *
* *    * *
**      **
*        *
```

Comment: The output you show does not match the requirement in OP's attached image. Note that there are no spaces between the pair of asterisks on the second row in OP's image

Comment: @Swifty Surely, if one is going to offer an answer, any caveats should be stated

Comment: You're right, and anyway I'd wrongly memorized the desired output!

Comment: @DarkKnight I don't see any attached image in the question. I assumed from the effort and posted output. Can you provide a link please.

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool OP posted a link as a comment

Comment: I updated my answer with desired output.

Comment: thank you for this! this approach helped a lot. you made it so much simpler and easier.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than calling *print()* multiple times it might be more efficient to build up the output string in a list.

Also, the list only needs half the rows because the second part of the output is just the inverse of the first.

e.g.,

```
def butterfly(n: int, c: str):
    m = n * 2 
    rows = []
    for h in range(n):
        r = c
        for w in range(1, m):
            r += c if w == h or w == m - h - 1 or w == m - 1 else ' '
        rows.append(r)
    print(*rows, *rows[::-1], sep='\n')

butterfly(5, '*')
```

**Output:**

```
*        *
**      **
* *    * *
*  *  *  *
*   **   *
*   **   *
*  *  *  *
* *    * *
**      **
*        *
```